# Will the findAll function of Spring Data JPA repository work if the entites are related as many to one or one to one or any such association?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is how the entity class looks like

```
@Entity
public class IndustryCode {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String industryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="industryCode")
    private Set<CarrierCodes> industryCodes;

@Entity
public class TechCode {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String techName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="techCode")
    private Set<CarrierCodes> techCodes;

@Entity
public class CarrierCodes {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CarrierCodesId id = new CarrierCodesId(); 

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("techCodeId")
    private TechCode techCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("industryCodeId")
    private IndustryCode industryCode;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class CarrierCodesId implements Serializable {
    private Long industryCodeId;
    private Long techCodeId;

@Entity
public class Register {
    @Id
    private Long mobileNumber;
    @ManyToOne
    // optional but nice to have consistent names
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="industryCode_id", referencedColumnName="industryCode_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="techCode_id", referencedColumnName="techCode_id")
        )
private CarrierCodes carrierCodes;
}

public class RegisterRepository extends JPARepository<Register,mobileNumber>{
}
```

My question is if I run findAll on Register table will I get the data for other related tables as well?

I mean using findAll(), will I get a List from which I can take Register obj and use .getCarrierCode().getIndustryCode().getIndustryName() to get industry name corresponding to carrierCode value in Register table

Comment: Yes, as long as you have them mapped correctly (which looks like you do), you should be able to pull all mapped tables' data...

Comment: Sure. Why do you think it shouldnt?